# How to push custom key and value into an array from an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, loops, associative-array

Take a look at this loop

```
$dataPoints1 = array();
$dataPoints2 = array();

$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M') as 'date', income, expense FROM `balance` group by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m');";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          array_push($dataPoints1, $row);  **desire one - to push into $dataPoints1 array from $row**
          array_push($dataPoints2, $row);  **desire two - to push into $dataPoints2 array from $row**
    }
}
```

My table,

| id | date | income | expense |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 20 | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 40 | 30 |
| 3 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 60 | 50 |

In **desire one**,  I want to push custom key and value with specific columns from an associative array ($row) like this,

```
$row
↓
{"label":"date","y":"income"}
```

In also **desire two**,

```
$row
↓
{"label":"date","y":"expense"}
```

Final output is like below,

```
dataPoints1
↓
[{"label":"May","y":"20"},{"label":"June","y":"40"},{"label":"July","y":"60"}]
```

```
dataPoints2
↓
[{"label":"May","y":"10"},{"label":"June","y":"30"},{"label":"July","y":"50"}]
```

I will echo with json_encode,

`echo  json_encode($dataPoints1);`

`echo json_encode($dataPoints2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better variable naming would help to make your code more clear.

Mysqli resultset objects can be iterated with `foreach()` as if they are arrays of associative arrays.

```
$income = [];
$expenses = [];
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    $income[] = ['label' => $row['date'], 'y' => $row['income']];
    $expenses[] = ['label' => $row['date'], 'y' => $row['expense']];
}
```

Comment: From your code, I also write like this,

array_push($dataPoints1, ['label'=>$row['date'], 'y'=>$row['income']]);
array_push($dataPoints2, ['label'=>$row['date'], 'y'=>$row['expense']]);

Comment: Yes, you can use `array_push()` also, but this is more verbose and an unnecessary function call.  I advise that you use my simpler / less expensive approach.

Comment: Is also need to push again into $dataPoints1 and $dataPoints2 from your array. $income = []; $expenses = [];

Comment: No, just use these better variable names instead of your vague variable names.